# Perl Error : Not an ARRAY reference

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute the following code, but it gives the error 
code :

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$xml = new XML::Simple (KeyAttr=>[]);# read XML file

$error =$xml->XMLin("trial.xml");
print "There are " . scalar@{$error->{problem}} . " problems.\n";
```

so it gives error prescribed at line :

```
print "There are " . scalar@{$error->{problem}} . " problems.\n";
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.
thank you.

Comment: Try `print Dumper($error);` after `$error =$xml->XMLin("trial.xml");`, seems, that the XML file is not read properly.

Comment: What is the XML input?

Answer (score 3):

As per the error message, `$error->{problem}` is not an array reference. The usual cause for this is that there is only one problem under error, as opposed to several, in which case XML::Simple doesn't generate an array.

Look for the `ForceArray` option in the docs: https://metacpan.org/module/GRANTM/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm#ForceArray-1-in

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation:

> ERROR HANDLING
>
> The XML standard is very clear on the issue of non-compliant
>   documents. An error in parsing any single element (for example a
>   missing end tag) must cause the whole document to be rejected.
>   XML::Simple will die with an appropriate message if it encounters a
>   parsing error.
>
> If dying is not appropriate for your application, you should arrange
>   to call XMLin() in an eval block and look for errors in $@. eg:
>
> ```
> my $config = eval { XMLin() };
> PopUpMessage($@) if($@);
> ```

regards, Matthias

Comment: @ikegami, I had a brain lag thinking the questioner wanted to catch XML errors, as the variable is called $error.